# How to use Automapper with ASP.NET Core 2.2 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
>       'myBackEnd.Entities.Striper' while attempting to activate 
>       'myBackEnd.Controllers.StripeController'.
>         at 
>       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

I am working on using Automapper for the first time.  I am also new to NET. I am using an HTTPPOST to get data from the front end in the format

```
    amount :  string;
    currency :  string;
    description :  string;
    token :  string;
    name: string;
    address_city: string;
    address_line1: string;
    address_line2: string;
    address_state: string;
    address_zip: string;
    address_country: string;
```

I have stripe.cs and stripeDto.cs files:

```
public class Striper
{
    public object Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public object Description { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address_line1 { get; set; }
    public string Address_line2 { get; set; }
    public string Address_state { get; set; }
    public string Address_zip { get; set; }
    public string Address_country { get; set; }
}
```

stripeDto:

```
public class StripeDto
{
    public object Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public object Description { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address_line1 { get; set; }
    public string Address_line2 { get; set; }
    public string Address_state { get; set; }
    public string Address_zip { get; set; }
    public string Address_country { get; set; }
}
```

This is the mapping profile file:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Striper, StripeDto>();
        CreateMap<StripeDto, Striper>();
    }
}
```

Finally this is the Controller:

```
private readonly AppDbContext _context;
private IMapper _mapper;

public StripeController(AppDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
{
     _context = context;
     _mapper = mapper;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> PostCreditCardData([FromBody] StripeDto stripeDto)
{
        Console.WriteLine("got this from the front end", stripeDto);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

          _context.StripeDto.Add(stripeDto);
         // Instantiate source object stripe
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        _striper = _mapper.Map<Striper>(stripeDto);
        return Ok(_striper);


 }
```

I get this error in visual studio "Unable to resolve service for type 'myBackEnd.Entities.Striper'"

Here is the startup.cs code:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Comment: Where is your `AutoMapper` configuration code in Startup class?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Your error does not seem to be about AutoMaper. Do you have any properties on the StripeContoller ?  Did you edit ('simplify') the posted code?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Whats your problem? Why have you down voted the correct answer? You did the same in past!

Comment: I had the same problem. And i am using a different project for converters/mapping. Use this code services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
MappingProfile - can be in another project.
Also you can use just CreateMap<Striper, StripeDto>().ReverseMap();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AutoMapper` configuration in `Startup` class  should be as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    //........
}
```

Comment: I am too afraid to use teamviewer.  How can I console log stripeDto from the front end in the HTTPPOST?

Comment: I am installng teamviewer

Comment: auto mapper has an extension for this in ASP.Net Core - `services.AddAutoMapper();`

Answer (score 2):

First, you must install Automapper dependency injection package:

Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Call services.AddAutoMapper() in ConfigureServices method in the Startup class.

More on this at:
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/

Comment: The author already did that. Otherwise the `IMapper` variable `_mapper` could not be used nor the controller could be instantiated.

Comment: I did add  the above packages.  I am getting the same error.  How can I console log what I get from the front end to eliminate AutoMapper?

Comment: @RobinGüldenpfennig, You are correct, off course! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late

but it's because of your startup and AutoMapper configuration

services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile).Assembly);

best regards